# How can I get \stackrel or \underset to produce stacked indexes of the same size?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, substack

I have been trying to use the `\stackrel` and the `\underset` commands to stack the expressions `i=1` and `j=1` under the summation symbol. The two commands do not seem to produce the effect I expect: `\stackrel` makes `i=1` smaller than `j=1` whereas `\underset` does the opposite.

I would like `i=1` and `j=1` to be of the same size. I would appreciate any help in making the two expressions to be of the same size. Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
Stacking indexes using \textbackslash{}stackrel:
\[\sum_{\stackrel{i=1}{j=1}}^{m}x_{i}y_{j}.\]
Stacking indexes using \textbackslash{}underset:
\[\sum_{\underset{j=1}{i=1}}^{m}x_{i}y_{j}.\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use `\substack`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
Using \verb|\substack|
\[\sum_{\substack{i=1\\j=1}}^{m}x_{i}y_{j}.\]
Stacking indexes using \textbackslash{}stackrel:
\[\sum_{\stackrel{i=1}{j=1}}^{m}x_{i}y_{j}.\]
Stacking indexes using \textbackslash{}underset:
\[\sum_{\underset{j=1}{i=1}}^{m}x_{i}y_{j}.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good examples!! Your helped me very much. Thanks.